# LaunchD programming in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, launchd

I am very new to LaunchD programming. I need to develop an application which needs to run in the background always. One of my friend suggest me that LaunchD programming is better for your requirement.I don't know how to use LaunchD programming. Can you guys suggest a best document or a sample code, to work on this?

Thanks in advance,
Chandra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Technical Note TN2083](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html) has a comprehensive description of daemons and background programs in Mac OS X.  Give that document a thorough read-through, and then come back with any further questions.